# Kafka error when sending message to topic

Tags: windows, apache-kafka

I am currently trying to create a producer and a consumer:

```
kafka-console-producer.bat --broker-list 127.0.0.1:9092 --topic test-topic 

kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --topic test-topic --from-beginning
```

An error occurred：

```
ERROR Error when sending message to topic test-topic with key: null, value: 2 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for test-topic-0:120001 ms has passed since batch creation
```

I checked my server.properties：

```
broker.id=1
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092

num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8

socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400

socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400

socket.request.max.bytes=104857600

log.dirs=D:/DataMining/kafka_2.12-3.5.1/kafka-logs

num.partitions=1

num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1

offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1

log.retention.hours=168

log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000

zookeeper.connect=localhost:5181

zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=18000

group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
```

The kafka version I am using is kafka_2.12-3.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

The Kafka producer doesn't send messages immediately. You can pass `--batch.size=1` to the producer to force it to flush a record